# Maximum Flow and Some Condition

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, network-flow

Suppose we have a Directed Graph and each edges has a positive capacity. if C is a positive constant, i say, if we add or subtract C to all edges capacity, the maximum flow, changed, (maybe increase or decrease). my question is, why if we multiply all edges capacity into C, the maximum flow is product by C?

why this is true?

Comment: In the [linear program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem#Linear_program_formulation) formulation of the problem, your statement follows immediately if you multiply all inequations by C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is true, because the maximum flow is also the *min cut*.

Let the old capacity be `w:E->N`, and the new capacity `w':E->N` such that `w'(e) = C*w(e)`

The min cut is the sum of `w'(e_i)` for each `e_i` in the cut, but since `w'(e_i) = C*w(e_i)`, we can say that the min cut is `sum (C*w(e_i)) = C * sum(w(e_i))`.

In addition, since for every cut X: `sum(w(e_i) | e_i in min cut) <= sum(w(e_i) | e_i in cut sum X)`, by multiplying with any constant `C` we get that:

```
C* sum(w(e_i) | e_i in min cut) <= C*sum(w(e_i) | e_i in some cut X)
sum(C * w(e_i) | e_i in min cut) <= sum(C*w(e_i) | e_i in some cut X)
sum(w'(e_i) | e_i in min cut) <= sum(w'(e_i) | e_i in some cut X)
```

And thus, the "old" min cut is also the "new" min cut (multiplied by C), and thus the overall max flow of the network increased by a factor of C.

Comment: you means the max flow is the same as min cut?

Comment: Dear @Lrrr,  you means it's equal? or like each others?

Comment: @MaryamGhizh they are equal, there is theorem in their name :D just look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem

Comment: Dear @amit, max flow is like to min cut or the same things?

Comment: @MaryamGhizh min cut = max flow, it's a very important concept of the problem.

Comment: @MaryamGhizh I will be happy to fix it. Where?

Comment: I think sum(w(e_i) | e_i in min cut) <=sum(w(e_i) | e_i in cut sum X, has not the same format.

Comment: @MaryamGhizh Thank you, I rephrased and I think it is more readable now.